# When is it required to use `schema_editor.connection.alias` in a django `migrations.RunPython` method?

Tags: django, django-migrations

When is it required to use `schema_editor.connection.alias` in a `migrations.RunPython` method and why?

When using RunPython in a data migration, [django advises](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) that you should use `schema_editor.connection.alias`:

```
from django.db import migrations

def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    # We get the model from the versioned app registry;
    # if we directly import it, it'll be the wrong version
    Country = apps.get_model("myapp", "Country")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    Country.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Country(name="USA", code="us"),
        Country(name="France", code="fr"),
    ])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

> **Warning**
>
> **RunPython** does not magically alter the connection of the models for you; any model methods you call will go to the default database unless you give them the current database alias (available from `schema_editor.connection.alias`, where `schema_editor` is the second argument to your function).*

But the docs section that [describes data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), it doesn't mention the `alias` at all:

```
from django.db import migrations

def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Person')
    for person in Person.objects.all():
        person.name = '%s %s' % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
        person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

Comment: I think it's required when you have [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases), and don't want to use the default one in the migration. If you have only one database defined in your settings, you don't need it.

Comment: When you are using two databases at the same time, the `schema_editor.connection.alias` is used to differentiate which database to run the RunPython function into. So you could have a different RunPython function for Oracle and a different one for PostgreSQL. For this to work you will need to have two databases specified in your `settings.py` file and to run migrations with the flag --database=postgres (if it is not your default database, if it is your default db then you can omit such flag). In case you are not using two databases you dont need to use
`schema_editor.connection.alias`.